Angular 17 @HostListener BeforeUnloadEvent
I have the following block of code in my Angular 17 application:
  @HostListener("window:beforeunload", ["$event"])
  onTabClose($event: BeforeUnloadEvent) {

    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.returnValue = "Here is some text";
    return "here is some text";
  }

When a user navigates away from the page, a confirmation dialog appears. However, closing the tab does NOT make a confirmation dialog appear. Setting a breakpoint in the method stops in the method, but still no dialog.
Is this a browser security issue?

Found the answer. The user must interact with the page prior to closing the tab for the confirmation to appear.
